# Included external file not processed by MathJax

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I would like to include in an html file, an external file that has math content that should be processed by MathJax. I tried a few ways to do this, and while the external file is being included in the html file, the math content in it is not processed. A minimal example to demonstrate this:

tst.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    This displays correctly: \(\phi\). 
    <inc></inc>
    <script>
     fetch("./tst.txt")
       .then(response => {
         return response.text()
       })
       .then(data => {
         document.querySelector("inc").innerHTML = data;
       });
    </script>
    <div id="abc"></div>
    <div id="def">
      <script>$("#def").load("tst.txt");</script>
    </div>
    <script>
     $(function(){
       $('#abc').load('tst.txt');
     });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

tst.txt:

```
\(\phi = 0\)
```

In the browser, the math content in the html file displays correctly, but not in the text from the included file . Is there a way to have the math content in the external file to be processed correctly?

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: I checked the MathJax documentation for dynamically loading pages. It seems that the issue  is probably as you suggested, but my initial attempts, even for the example they provide does not seem to work, but I will check further and if it works, I will accept your answer. My attempt so far, has been to include the following: ````    <div id="math"></div>
    <script>
     MathJax.typeset(() => {
       const math = document.querySelector('#math');
       math.innerHTML = '$$\\frac{a}{1-a^2}$$';
       return math;
     });
    </script> ```` but there is no change in the displayed page.

Comment: When the page has fully loaded run `MathJax.typeset()` in the console, does the Mathematics get rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is that the file is being pulled into the page only after MathJax has rendered the Maths. Therefore you would need to 'ask' MathJax to search through the page for any more Maths and render the new maths.

From MathJax documentation:

> If you are writing a dynamic web page where content containing mathematics may appear after MathJax has already typeset the rest of the page, then you will need to tell MathJax to look for mathematics in the page again when that new content is produced. To do that, you need to use the MathJax.typeset() method. This will cause MathJax to look for unprocessed mathematics on the page and typeset it, leaving unchanged any math that has already been typeset.